# Different ways of adding entity in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have these domain objects in EntityFramework in this hierarchy.

```
Product
      --> ProductAssets
```

I would like to add an asset to Product

```
var asset  = new ProductAsset
{
     Product = product,
     Name = "Asset 1"
};
```

Are there going to be any differences if I add the entity using one of the methods below?

### Method 1

```
product.ProductAssets.Add(asset);
```

### Method 2

```
UnitOfWork.ProductAsset.Add(asset);
```

-Alan-

Comment: `product.ProductAssets.Add(asset);` means you don't need to set the product on your asset. Otherwise, they're equivalent *assuming* you add/track the `product`.

Answer (score 0):

If `ProductAsset` is a separate entity altogether then add to that collection instead directly like below (I am pointing to your mentioned `Method2`)

```
context.ProductAsset.Add(asset);
```